# Catch NameError and NoMethodError with rescue_from in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, nameerror

I have this *ApplicationController*:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :class_breadcrumb
end
```

I require every controller to define its own class_breadcrumb() method.
And I'd like to show a message, without raising an exception, if that method doesn't exist.
Finally, I want every other exception to fallback to the standard xml 500 page.

I felt it would be pretty simple to handle with this rescue_from block:

```
rescue_from "NameError" do |e|
  if e.to_s.include?('class_breadcrumb')
    flash.now["alert-danger"] = "You didn't provide a breadcrumb for #{request.fullpath}! Please send us a feedback including this message!"
    render params[:action]
  else
    # default behavior
    render :xml => e, :status => 500
  end
end
```

And it works! But when any other exception raises from within a controller... let's suppose I'm calling an undefined method like this:

```
<%= undefined_method_that_raise_an_exception %>
```

I see a blank page with this message:

> *Internal Server Error*
>
> *no implicit conversion of NameError into String*

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out!

```
# rescue NoMethodError
def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
  if method == 'class_breadcrumb'
    flash.now["alert-danger"] = "You didn't provide a breadcrumb for #{request.fullpath}! Please send us a feedback including this message!"
    render params[:action]
  end
end
```

This is metaprogramming Ruby! That's why I've just convinced myself to buy this book and get the pain out: http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby

Comment: That's certainly one way to get around the trouble you were having-- but I would recommend you add an `else` for your `if` that calls `super` so that `method_missing` continues up the method lookup chain and appropriate exceptions are raised for methods other than `class_breadcrumb`.